# Issues inserting data into my database after user has logged in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a script that I would like to have run using jQuery and PHP.  After a user logs in, they fill out a form and hit the 'save' button.  The jQuery attaches a click event which runs the PHP script.  I've got console logs at certain break points and I'm showing that my script is actually stopping at a certain point, however, I have no idea why.

**TABLE CREATION AND DATABASE CONNECTION**

```
$create_table_scenarios = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $scenarios(id VARCHAR(25), PRIMARY KEY(id))";
mysqli_query($connect, $create_table_scenarios);
```

I know that the connection is being made and the table is being created because it shows up in the database.

**THE FORM**

```
<form id="scenario_builder" method="post" action"../php/processing.php">
    <div id="form_general" class="form_view">
        <h3>General Info</h3>
        <div class="half">
            <fieldset for="center_menu">
                <label>Center:</label>
                <div class="select" name="center_menu" id="center_menu">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                    <div class="option-menu">
                        <div class="option"></div>
                            <?php
                                $query = "SELECT * FROM $centers";
                                $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                    $center_name = "{$row['center']}";
                                    echo "<div class='option'><input type='hidden' name='center' id='center' value='" .$center_name ."' />" .$center_name ."</div>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="button" value="Save" />
</form>
```

**PROCESSOR**

```
ob_start();
require("../includes/header.php");
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $center = $_POST["center"];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `$scenarios`(`id`) VALUES('" .$center ."')";
    mysqli_query($connect, $query);
}
ob_clean();
echo json_encode(array("success" => 1));
```

**jQUERY**

```
$("input[id='save']").on("click", function(){
    console.log("Save clicked");
    $.post("..php/processing.php", {}, function(response){
        if(response.success == "1"){
            console.log("Data entered.");
        }
        else{
            console.log("Data not entered.");
        }
    }, "json");
})
```

The only console message I'm getting is the `"Save clicked"` one.  So, for some reason, the `$.post` function isn't running.  Can someone show me why based on the code I've provided?  On a different note, yes, I understand that my queries are vulnerable to injection, I'm just trying to get the basics to work right now.

Comment: This `$.post("..php/processing.php"` if that's not a typo, you're missing a slash `$.post("../php/processing.php"` - Plus, `$scenarios` has been defined, correct?

Comment: That wasn't a typo, it was something I messed up in my code.  However, after fixing it, the same exact thing is happening.  And, yes, $scenarios has been defined.  I'm not sure if the problem is with the jQuery or the PHP because even before I added the jQuery click event handler, it wasn't working.  I'm going to post this particular portion of the form as well.

Comment: Zavg deleted his answer, and wrote this inside it, which btw, I can still see the answer since I'm a 10k+ member: *"As @fred-ii mentioned it seems that you have a typo with missing slash in url. Also you forgot to pass center argument in your AJAX post request

   `$.post("../php/processing.php", {center:1}, function(response){`

Of course, instead of `1` in the above code you should use your value for center parameter."* - See if that fixes it. If it does, I may be able to undelete his answer and you could accept it.

Comment: How would I replace the center:1 parameter if the value can be different, ie, it depends on what the user selects.

Comment: That I couldn't say. Zavg would have to either comment here, if he's still looking at the question, and/or undelete his answer.

Comment: Ok, hopefully he re-answers with a solution...........I'm starting to think I'm in over my head with this project.

Comment: By the way, your POST variable `$_POST["center"]` and `<div class="select" name="center" id="center">` I don't think that's valid. That would most likely need to be an input of sorts. DIVs don't qualify as (form) POSTs. I could be wrong though, but it doesn't look right to me. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything  as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connect))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: I think you're right.  I'm probably going to have to add a hidden input field which takes the values from the div and process it that way.

Comment: That would probably work.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer to reflect the hidden input field, so, now the field is being entered into the database, but the data is blank.

Comment: TBH, jQuery/JS is not something I know very well. Wish I could help you out more, but I won't be able to.

Comment: The jQuery is actually working now.  The PHP is inserting blank data into the database now.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see you are double submitting the form. You once submit the form due to the form's submit button push and the second time you submit the form with the AJAX request due to the event handler you added to the button. You either let the form submit with a regular POST, or on the submit button press you prevent the event's default behavior and submit the data by AJAX.